# Sharing MS Database with Multiple Users

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have a MS Access Database that I need to share with multiple users in the entire state.  Right now I split the database and placed the backend on a shared network drive and distributed the front end, but the issue I'm having is that offices further away can't enter a record in a timely manner (one office took over 2 hours).

We do have SharePoint, but it's on a 2010 server and our MS Access is 2013 and I'm told because of this, access won't link up to SharePoint and this is not an option.

Someone in my office mentioned something about replicating a database...is this something that will work?  If not, are there any suggestions?

Comment: [This blog post](http://accesshosting.com/how-access-services-2013-has-changed-since-2010-and-what-that-means-for-access-developers) says that "Access 2013 and Access 2010 can both publish to SharePoint 2010 and the old Access Web Services 2010" so you may not be totally out of luck, but note that I am *not* an expert on Access+SharePoint. If you're lucky, Albert might see this question and give you some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Replication in Access was killed in Access 2007.

SharePoint is not an option except if you start from scratch, and the shared lists and/or various web apps you can create are seriously limited compared to your present desktop solution.

Basically, you have three options:

1. *Upgrade your WAN* to 100 Mbit/s low-latency quality fibre connection
2. Create a *Terminal Server* hosting your application. Remote users will access this via standard Remote Desktop Connection
3. *Upgrade your backend to SQL Server Express* (free) and set up an in-house or outsourced server hosting this

The first options require zero coding, while the last takes a little but not much, and that is well documentated (just bing/google on this).